# Joining 3 Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, discrete-mathematics

I need a little bit of help in creating this query. I'm joining `TableA` and `TableB` and getting a value out of it; then joining `TableA` and `TableC` and getting a value out if it. Finally I am substracting both values.

I'm not sure how to write this in a single query using a lot of `JOIN` or if I just do 2 subqueries and then substract them.

So far I have something like:

```
SELECT SUM(A.quantity) From TableA JOIN Table B WHERE ...
```

then

```
SELECT SUM(A.quantity) From TableA JOIN Table C WHERE ...
```

Given the chance that maybe `TableA` and `TableB` have no result, but `TableA` and `TableC` does, or viceversa, or maybe both have or maybe both won't,  I can't just `JOIN` `TableA` and `TableB` and `TableC`

Comment: What do you intend to do if either produces no result? Use 0, and potentially end up with a negative when subtracted?

Comment: I have COALESCE in mind, but that is not what I'm asking right now

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `cross join`:

```
select coalesce(s1.q1, 0) - coalesce(s2.q2, 0)
from (SELECT SUM(A.quantity) as q1 From TableA JOIN Table B WHERE ...) s1 cross join
     (SELECT SUM(A.quantity) as q2 From TableA JOIN Table C WHERE ...) s2;
```

If one of the result sets returns `NULL`, the `coalesce()` treats the value as `0`.